# Reset Loop get_posts();

Tags: loop

I add too single.php menu:

```
<ul id="nav">
<?php
$all_posts = get_posts(array(

));

// this variable will contain all the posts in a associative array
// with three levels, for every year, month and posts.

$ordered_posts = array();

foreach ($all_posts as $single) {
$year  = mysql2date('Y', $single->post_date);
$month = mysql2date('F', $single->post_date);
// specifies the position of the current post
$ordered_posts[$year][$month][] = $single;
}

// iterates the years
foreach ($ordered_posts as $year => $months) { ?>
<li>
    <?php echo $year ?>

    <ul class="active">
    <?php foreach ($months as $month => $posts ) { // iterates the moths ?>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $single ) { // iterates the posts ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($single->ID);// echo   '#post-'.$single->ID;?>"><?php echo get_the_title($single->ID); ?></a></li>
        </li>
    <?php } // ends foreach $posts ?>

    <?php } // ends foreach for $months ?>
    </ul>

</li> <?php
} // ends foreach for $ordered_posts
?>
</ul>
```

After this code a got loop to print single post:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">


    <?php /* The loop */ ?>
    <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php twentythirteen_post_nav(); ?>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
```

but on every single page, I have the latest post.

Pleas help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$posts` is a global var used by WordPress, change that to something unique and it'll work as expected.

Also fyi, `rewind_posts();` isn't necessary here, you haven't run the loop yet, so there's nothing to rewind.